# How does pre processing the data using move to front algorithm helps huffman coding?

Tags: compression, preprocessor, huffman-code

I need to compress a text using **huffman coding**. Before doing that I need to pre process the input text using **Move to front(MTF)** algorithm. As the output of mtf algorithm gives me an array of index of the position of the character with lower index for the frequently used character, how will this help for huffman encoding? Can anyone help me the an example on how these two can be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your data. If the same letters are used often locally, MTF can reduce the entropy of the data, and Huffman then can take advantage of that reduction to compress the data.

On typical text, MTF won't help a lot (might even hurt), but MTF helps quite a bit after a Burrows-Wheeler transform, which tends to group the same characters in a reversible way. You can also do run-length encoding after the MTF.

How to merge them is simply to do the MTF, and the Huffman-code the resulting integer indices.